# Keeping your personal rpc endpoint address private in a react front end hosted by Netlify

Tags: react, web3.js, react-native

a somewhat specific question here but maybe someone has the same set up as me..

I have a javascript app that is hosted on Netlify, that interacts with the solana mainnet.  I've recently discovered the need to use my own private RPC node rather than the public one so I have code like the following:

```
        <ConnectionProvider endpoint="https://solana-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/MYENDPOINTHERE">
            <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
                <WalletModalProvider>
                    <AirDropApp/>
                </WalletModalProvider>
            </WalletProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
```

What I am trying to understand is how to keep the MYENDPOINTHERE bit secret in this react app.  Netlify have support for using AWS lambda functions to get data (e.g https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-access-secret-api-keys-using-netlify-functions-in-a-react-app/).. but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to actually use them for this instance.

Surely this must be a solved problem (albeit not necessarily via netlify, but i imagine if i knew what the solution looked like, i might be able to find out the specifics of how to do it with them.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never make an endpoint private in frontends when people are using it(it will log on the networks tab of developer tools). You should instead contact your RPC provider and only allow requests from your domain.

Comment: This is.. a much simpler approach.